# Adding .so lib into .pro file in eclipse. C++ / Eclipse / Linux

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse, static

Im working on app (C++ / QT / Eclipse Helios) which allows to connect to database. On some distributions of Linux (SUSE) there is a problem with libraries. 'error while loading shared libraries: libldap-2.4.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory' Is there a possibility to add those libs into app build? I tried adding them into .pro file

```
FORMS += 
linux-g++{
    INCLUDEPATH += source/include
    LIBS += source/libldap-2.4.so.2 \    
    source/libldap_r-2.4.so.2 \
    source/libldif-2.4.so.2 \
```

but it doesn't work at all.
Any ideas?

Comment: You should add the location into LD_LIBRARY_PATH or ld.config.

Comment: If the shared library is missing on SUSE, you should just install it there. The LD_LIBRARY_PATH or ld.config tells the run-time linker where to find the shared library if installed in a non-standard location (they have little influence on the compile-time linking).

Cross-compiling between Linux distributions is not as easy as just compiling the program on the actual target machine (shared library dependencies will be resolved correctly).

Answer (score 0):

Well, installing libs on SUSE was not an option. I resolved that problem using small bash script

```
#!/bin/bash
DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$DIR/lib
./myprog
```

and I put missing libs in folder `/lib`. Only inconvenience is that you have to run app using this script, not clicking the app itself. Anyway, thanks for the response! :)